# Why won't my laptop output to 1440p on home monitor but will at work?

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi, resolution

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out; hoping you all can help me out. My work laptop is a 1.5 year old HP Zbook G3 with an nVidia Quadro M1000M. At work, it is hooked up to an HP thunderbolt 3 dock which is pushing 2 1440p monitors (via displayports plugged into the dock), and is working fine.

At home, I have a Dell U2713HM 1440p monitor (HDMI 1.4). No matter what I do though, I can't get my laptop to display at 1440p on this monitor; it only will display at 1080p. I've tried connecting with several different brand new HDMI 2.0 cables (Laptop HDMI port to Monitor HDMI port) and I've tried connecting from the thunderbolt 3 port on laptop to HDMI port on monitor using a brand new USB-C to HDMI dongle that says it supports 4K@30Hz.

Any idea why this won't work for me? I've updated to all the latest drivers. as far as I can tell. This has been driving me nuts for weeks.

Comment: Seems that you need a [DisplayPort](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/771094/quadro-1000m-not-displaying-2560x1600-resolution/) or a [docking station](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-P-and-W-Series-Mobile/W520-2560-x-1440-through-docking-station-NVidia-Quadro-1000M/td-p/944993) to reach that resolution

Comment: That doesn't make sense becuase I tried using a 4k capable HDMI cable through a 4k capable dongle connected to the 4k capable thunderbolt 3 port.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it to work by using HDMI output on laptop to HDMI input on monitor, and then creating a custom resolution in the nVidia control panel: 2560x1440@30Hz. Would not do 60Hz unfortunately.